# Retrieving html from a element (attribute) of DOM

Tags: jquery, url, object

Given:

```
var imageURL1 = $(".Img1").attr("src");
```

If I alert `imageURL1`, I have something like:

```
[object Object]
```

Lets say I want to retrieve the real value of the URL and pass to another variable in the way that I can put e.g a new attribute `src`.

```
<img class="Img2" src= "'+imageURL1+ '" alt="etc..etc.." />
```

This dont work because the url will be `http://[Object/Object]` or similar.

**How can I get the HTML value of that and create a URL?**

Comment: Not certain interpret Question correctly ? Is requirement to set or get `src` attribute of `img` element ?

Comment: i want to get the url value and convert to html...imageURL1 is a variable. how to get the value of the url inside of it and pass it to another image?

Comment: so instead of seeing [object Object] i get a real URL ...the html inside that..dontk now how to explain sorry. the string ?

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using returns an Object representing the jQuery selector.

```
var imageURL1 = $("Img1").attr("src");
```

It will work if you give your `img` an id "Img1" and use the following:

```
var imageURL1 = $("#Img1").attr("src");
alert(imageURL1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/40yufa1g/

Comment: Hi Carlos. I set a class image not the selector but now it give s not result. blank,. do you want to see the page  here   ?  http://www.paolobergomi.it/new-gallery/night/                                 var share1 = $(".lb-image").attr("src");
 
  alert(share1);

Comment: It works that way because jQuery `$(".lb-image")` returns a selector for all elements with "lb-image" as class name so you need to use id instead. If you just want the first element of that class you can do `$(".lb-image")[0].attr("src");`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, setting like this make disappear all the snippet :(

Answer (score 0):

One way to set , get `img` element `src` attribute is to utilize `document.images[index]` , where `index` is an integer representing the 0-based index of selected `img` element within `document`

```js
// get `src` of first `img` element within `document`
var imgURL1 = document.images[0].src;
// set `src` of second `img` element within `document`
document.images[1].src = imgURL1;
// log `imgURL1`
console.log(imgURL);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature" />
<img src="" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks,.  i set that way but it takes the url of the first image, my brand, and replace the first image of my gfallery with a n enlarged brand. there is a way to take the .lb-image class img and share the URL? that is my aim thanks a lot

Comment: this not working, dont know but i t seems correct to me.. var imgURL1 = document.getElementsByClassName("lb-image").getAttribute("src");

Comment: _"this not working, dont know but i t seems correct to me.. var imgURL1 = document.getElementsByClassName("lb-image").getAttribute("src");"_ Try including `index` of element  `document.getElementsByClassName("lb-image")[0].getAttribute("src");` , where `0` is 0-based index of collection elements returned by `.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0):

you probably have several images with the class **"img1"**, thats why jquery returns an object.

Comment: exactly, but as you see in lightbox (u can check from my website gallery) wonce you open an image, it create a new div withe the image inside, the .lb-image class and display in the center of the screen,. the trick is to get that value and pass it to the add to any. that is the tricky point that i am not able to sort so far. thanks anyway for help

Comment: this should work. there is only a lb-image once I clicked on the single thumb, the one related to the image selected and opened in the center of the page. so why does not work, this???? var imgURL1 = document.getElementsByClassName("lb-image").getAttribute("src");